# Using a variable to point to a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to a comparison between many different items using a Spearman test(from the package pspearman). I would like to have a way to automate the switching in of variables so that rather than running it one of at a time and running it would be able to just switch in each one and run all at once.

I tried to pass the list of the vectors that I would like to compare it to.

```
spearman.test(access_sam2$Area,access_sam2$B)
```

All the columns are in the dataframe access_sam2. In the y, position there is a list of columns that I need to run:

"CD8_PD1, CD8_PDL1, CD8_GBNEG_FOXP3, CD8_GBNEG_FOXP3_CD45RO, CD8_GBNEG_FOXP3NEG_CD45RO, CD8NEG_PD1, CD8NEG_PDL1, CD8NEG_FOXP3, CD8NEG_FOXP3_CD45RO,CD68_PDL1, CK_PDL1."

The problem is that it is not possible to use indexes because they are not sequential columns, and has 660+ columns.
I could write 7 spearman tests but changing all 7 for each Area variable seems inefficent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set `yvars` to be a character variable which names the columns you want or is a numeric variable that gives their column numbers. We have shown the first few elements of it below.  Then we define a function which takes a variable name and outputs the spearman test.  Finally use `Map` to apply that function to each component of `yvars`.

```
yvars <- c("CD8_PD1", "CD8_PDL1", "CD8_GBNEG_FOXP3")
sptest <- function(yvar) spearman.test(access_sam2$Area, access_sam2[[yvar]])
Map(sptest, yvars)
```

### Reproducible example

Below is a reproducible example using the `mtcars` data frame that comnes with R.

```
library(pspearman)

yvars <- c("cyl", "disp", "hp")
sptest <- function(yvar) spearman.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars[[yvar]])
Map(sptest, yvars)
```

Comment: How would I go about naming the columns that I want to specifically include? Do I just set yvars<- c("B,C,D,E,F,G,H")

Comment: We have no idea what the names look like or what the rule is to choose them.  It's up to you to provide a question which unambiguously describes your problem.  In the absence of that I have assumed a rule in the answer to give the general idea.

Comment: There is a lot of overlap between the names of the columns

Comment: I want the list as posted rather than being defined as a rule

Comment: I have revised the answer to use a fixed list.

Comment: I am getting the error:  Error in spearman.test(access_sam2$Area_mTLS_intra, access_sam2[[yvar]]) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length

Comment: Have added a reproducible example. Also changed `lapply` to `Map` which gives the same output except it also add component names to it.